# d3.js Accessing x y Coordinates

Tags: javascript, csv, parsing, d3.js

I want to create a scatterplot and I need x y coordinates.

I have to extract the coordinates from a csv file that stores the data in this way:

```
ARRESTEE HOME CITY - MAPPED (header)
PESOTUM IL 61863 (39.906012°, -88.281892°)
KOKOMO IN 46902 (40.443256°, -86.114184°)
GLENVIEW IL 60026 (42.092102°, -87.837869°)
```

How can I access the coordinates in parentheses? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback function to format the data.

```
var data = []
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
data = data.map(function(d) { /* format as needed */ });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

```
var dt = []
    d3.csv("test.csv", function(error,data) {
    dt = data.map(function(d){ console.log(d["MAPPED(header)"].split(',')); });
    });
```

Also, to do this, had to edit your CSV file in below format
ARRESTEE HOME CITY - MAPPED (header)
PESOTUM IL 61863 "(39.906012°, -88.281892°)"
KOKOMO IN 46902 "(40.443256°, -86.114184°)"
GLENVIEW IL 60026 "(42.092102°, -87.837869°)"

Added double quotes around last column. This was done if it's a comma separated CSV file. If it's space separated CSV, then I think this change is not required.

Comment: If I use `d.points = +d["Arrestee Home City - Mapped"] ` in the function is not enough. How can I parse the x and y coordinates?

Comment: can you provide a better example of the input file? the one in your example is not CSV, the only comma is separating the coordinates within the parentheses...

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @ssiluveru! It is possible to use the code below to save x and y coordinate and convert them to a number?  
     `d3.csv("Urbana_Police_Arrests_Since_1988.csv", function(error, data) {

      data.forEach(
          function(d){



          d.x = +d["MAPPED"].split(',')
          d.y= +d["MAPPED"].split(',')

      });`

Comment: @cowbert The API from the dataset is [link]( https://data.urbanaillinois.us/resource/x5m7-in2r.csv). I only want to create a scatterplot with the coordinates from arrestee_home_city_mapped_zip. To access the x,y coordinates I need to split arrestee_home_city_mapped_zip. It is possible with split(',')...like in the example from ssiluveru? Thanks!

Comment: From the file you linked It looks like the field with the coordinates you're looking at is `arrestee_home_city_mapped` which has data in the form of `POINT (x y)`. You'll need to use a regular expression to parse that to get `x` and `y`: `d.xy = d['arrestee_home_city_mapped'].split(/([\d\.-]+)\s([\d\.-]+)/); d.x = +d.xy[1]; d.y = +d.xy[2]`

Comment: Yes, you can. d.x = +parseInt(d["MAPPED"].split(',')[0]);  d.y = +parseInt(d["MAPPED"].split(',')[1]).